# Value Error while importing data into postgres table using psycopg2

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I have a tuple as below

```
data = ({'weather station name': 'Substation', 'wind': '6 km/h', 'barometer': '1010.3hPa', 'humidity': '42%', 'temperature': '34.5 C', 'place_id': '001D0A00B36E', 'date': '2016-05-10 09:48:58'})
```

I am trying to push the values from the above tuple to the postgres table using the code below:

```
try:                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='WeatherForecast' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='****'")                                                                                                         
    cur = con.cursor()                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO weather_data(temperature,humidity,wind,barometer,updated_on,place_id) VALUES (%(temperature)f, %(humidity)f, %(wind)f, %(barometer)f, %(date)s, %(place_id)d)""", final_weather_data)
    ver = cur.fetchone()                                                                                                                                                                                                
    print(ver)                                                                                                                                                                                                          

except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:                                                                                                                                                                                     
    print('Error {}'.format(e))                                                                                                                                                                                         
    sys.exit(1)

finally:                                                                                                                                                                                                                

  if con:                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     con.close()
```

Where datatype of each field in the DB is as below:
id serial NOT NULL,

```
temperature double precision NOT NULL,
humidity double precision NOT NULL,
wind double precision NOT NULL,
barometer double precision NOT NULL,
updated_on timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
place_id integer NOT NULL,
```

When i run the code to push the data into postgres table using psycopg2, it is raising an error `"ValueError: unsupported format character 'f'"`

I hope the issue is in formatting. Am using Python3.4

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries):

> The variables placeholder must always be a `%s`, even if a different placeholder (such as a `%d` for integers or `%f` for floats) may look more appropriate:
>
> ```
> >>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (%d)", (42,)) # WRONG
> >>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (%s)", (42,)) # correct
> ```

While, your SQL query contains all type of placeholders:

```
"""INSERT INTO weather_data(temperature,humidity,wind,barometer,updated_on,place_id) 
   VALUES (%(temperature)f, %(humidity)f, %(wind)f, %(barometer)f, %(date)s, %(place_id)d)"""
```

Comment: I tried changing all the placeholder to %s. But am receiving TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str.

Comment: All the data you have in the `dict` is in string format e.g. `'wind': '6 km/h'` while you expect `wind double precision NOT NULL` which is a double value. You first need to write a converter which will explicitly format the data that you have into what should be entered in the database and then come to postgres for the insertion bit.

Comment: Well, i changed the field datatype to be character varying. Now i tried changing all the placeholders to %s. Still the error "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str." remains same.